# sqlite3, How do I insert the value at the position of second row

Tags: mysql, sqlite

This is my existing table

```
1|Dennis|456731|NOT CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
2|MOTO|4568971|NOT CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
3|KARBAN|4568971|CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
4|Lenovo|4568971|CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
```

How do I insert the new value at the position of second row.

```
1|Dennis|456731|NOT CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
2|Gosling|456731|NOT CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
3|MOTO|4568971|NOT CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
4|KARBAN|4568971|CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
5|Lenovo|4568971|CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
```

Comment: Dont do that. Dont mess with the auto increment value. You can use another column to indicate an order. For instance a datetime column.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables generally do not have any inherent order (well, there *is* the notion of an ordered clustered index, but generally we cannot rely on this).  So, if you want the new `Gosling` record to appear second, then you should provide some column which generates this order.

Your expected output almost looks like it is sorted alphabetically by name.  So, the following query might be acceptable to you:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY name;
```